# Git: copy a file from one repository to another (unrelated) repository

Tags: git, scp, cp

I have 2 git repositories

- Rep1 is on my local computer. It contains a file called file.txt which is tracked.
- Rep2 is in a cluster folder.

Both folders are "local" - i.e. they do not have origins to push and pull to.

I would like to copy file.txt from Rep1 to Rep2. Can I just:

- Use scp from Rep1 to Rep2
- Git add file.txt in Rep2

These repositories are not related so I literally only want to copy a file from one to the other. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy file from a directory1 to a directory2, it has nothing to do with git, and especially nothing to do with the "from" repository.

Just copy the file normally (with `scp` for instance) then track it in the other repository using `git add`